# call to undefined method llluminate\support\facades\request::save()

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to save an input into my database called requests

The error points to my requestController.php when the data is trying to be saved.This is the code to handle saving the data into the database called requests.

```
$request = new Request;
```

These are the data trying to save:

```
$request->product_name = $posted['product_name'];    
$request->product_description = $posted['product_description' ];
$request->email = $posted['email'];   
$request->user_id = Auth::user()->I'd;
```

error reporting from this code:

```
$request->save();
```

Why do I get this error exception?

Comment: Request is a facade in Laravel, you'll need to namespace your model or name it something else. See here in Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information

Answer (score 5):

`Request` is the name of a facade in Laravel. That's why the error message says it's looking for the `save()` method on the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` class. You'll want to either namespace your `Request` class or rename it to something else. I would prefer the latter option, myself.

Besides that, this line looks like it should cause the script to crash: `$request->user_id = Auth::user()->I'd;` - it should probably be `->id;`, I assume?